# Color Overlay UIButton Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm having this issue when trying to overlay a `UIButton`'s `Image` with a color.

The overlay color is appearing underneath the `Image`.

Here is the code that I have in my `drawRect` method (I have subclassed `UIButton`):

```
(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGRect bounds = self.imageView.bounds;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, self.imageView.image.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, bounds, [self.imageView.image CGImage]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, bounds);
}
```

Any ideas on how to get the red color on top of the `Image`?

Comment: Is your UIButton set as a Custom Button rather that RoundRect? With custom you should be on the right track:-)

Comment: @JeffKranenburg The button is initialised like this:
    `paletteButton = [PaletteButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [paletteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"98-palette.png"]   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    paletteButton.frame = CGRectMake(110, 13, 24, 20);`

Comment: Why don't you call `[super drawRect:]`, by the way?

Comment: @H2CO3 didn't know I needed to, but had a look at Apple's docs:
"If you subclass UIView directly, your implementation of this method (`drawRect`) does not need to call `super`. However, if you are subclassing a different view class, you should call `[super drawRect:rect]` at some point in your implementation." Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Succeeded with this hacky code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage* img = [self imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    CGRect bounds = self.imageView.bounds;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2].CGColor);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, bounds, img.CGImage);
    CGContextFillRect(context, bounds);
}
```

It seems the image is drawn after drawRect so unless you make it nil, it goes on top of whatever you draw there.

This is solution is not final. I'll edit it with what I get to next.

EDIT: The right solution is to add a semi-transparent UIView on top of the image like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        UIView* tintView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        tintView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2];
        tintView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [self addSubview:tintView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        UIView* tintView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        tintView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2];
        tintView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [self addSubview:tintView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Note: you should do this in your UIButton subclass.